# How do php acclerators work?

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so I've running so pretty large queries on my site and its been running up the mysql resources. My admin questioned whether I've tried different php accelerators but I've never installed one before. So I did some research on it, and I'm curious do I need to make any modifications to my actual php codes or do I just install an accelerator and let it take effect? I need ways to optimize my load and reduce the amount of resources being used on the server.

Comment: Yes, try it out. Without details it's impossible for anyone here to conclude if it'll help. PHP accelerators don't have any bearing on SQL queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"PHP accelerators" are opcode caches; they save the server from having to re-interpret PHP files on every request. The savings is somewhere in the realm of 1% of CPU load, and it won't help you one bit if your problem is with the database's resource usage.

Comment: +1, but I could argue with you about the 1% :)

Comment: well I guess there's no hope there, thanks for the info Dan

Answer (score 1):

> Most PHP accelerators work by caching the compiled bytecode of PHP
>   scripts to avoid the overhead of parsing and compiling source code on
>   each request (some or all of which may never even be executed). To
>   further improve performance, the cached code is stored in shared
>   memory and directly executed from there, minimizing the amount of slow
>   disk reads and memory copying at runtime.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_accelerator

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you need to accelerate your SQL queries, not your PHP code.

Comment: Tom you are right any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: @user761479: There are about 2,000,000,000 resources available online about optimising your database queries.

Answer (score -1):

Here are a list of PHP accelerators that you can evaluate and install
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators

I've used APC, which I believe is one of the most popular PHP accelerators. One thing that it does is basically cache function calls and arguments, so that subsequent calls to the same function with the same arguments will have its return value cached, and not have to recompute everything.

Comment: Does it APC really do that return cacheing? How would it know about the side effects in your code?

Comment: I'm sure glad it doesn't actually do that, since any non-deterministic function would return the wrong values on every call after the first! Imagine if `time()` didn't return the current time...

Comment: @Dan: I know, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: It doesn't, at least not out of the box. I have APC installed on all my servers (and it's scheduled to be made part of PHP core). It just caches code. There's an API for APC in PHP to store/retrieve your own values into/out of the cache, which you could use to implement that, if you wanted.

Comment: Actually, I'm talking out of my a$$. It does opcode caching. Well, can you guys please explain this behavior: I visit a page with an underlying PHP function that does something (prints it out); I go over and edit the PHP file on the server, changing the innards of the function. Refresh the page, but it does the same thing, although the function should be doing otherwise. It doesn't take effect until I clear the opcode cache.